# nextjs - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: next.js

I'm using nextjs as framework trying to display titles using slug

My code in [slug].js file is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const slug = ({proDetail}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query
  console.log(proDetail[slug].title)
  return (<div>title:{proDetail[slug].title}</div>)
}
export default slug
```

In the above code(line no.3) proDetails is an object in _app.js which is given as a prop for [slug].js

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
   var proDetail = {
     s1: {  title: "Tomato", disc:"lorem" },
     s2: {  title: "Pepper", disc:"lorem" },
     s3: {  title: "Lettuce", disc:"lorem" },
     s4: {  title: "Carrot", disc:"lorem" },
     s5: {  title: "Radish", disc:"lorem" }
   }
    return <>
       <Component proDetail={proDetail} {...pageProps}/>
     </>
  }
```

[image: error picture]

I want my title to displed the corresponding title in an object for different url's http://localhost:3000/s{i} (where "i" is number from 1 to 5 as i have only s1 to s5 keys in my proDetail object)

My motive is to change the title if I change my URL but getting  **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')**  if I use proDetail["s2"].title in place of proDetail[slug].title then my title is displayed on web page, but this displays only key:s2 's title

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const slug = ({proDetail}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query
  return (<div>title:{proDetail["s2"].title}</div>)
}
```

[image: title display http://localhost:3000/s(anyValue)]

but display **title: Pepper** will appear even in http://localhost:3000/s(anyValue) because I have changed my HTML.

How to resolve this TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title'). I do not want create seperate pages for each title and wanted to make work with slug.

I understood that console statements and html are rendered before getting slug value getting defined but how to overcome this error

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const slug =(({proDetail}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  let {slug} =router.query
  console.log(slug)
  return (<div>title:
    {slug === undefined ? 'Loading...' : JSON.stringify(proDetail[slug].title)} 
    </div>)
})
export default slug
```

I understood that I can asses **proDetail[slug].title** only if my slug is not undefined

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using `useEffect` is almost correct, but you need to verify `slug` value is empty or not.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if(slug) {
      console.log(proDetail[slug].title);
   }
}, [slug])
```

The reason for this is `useEffect` is also triggered for the first rendering when `slug` is not available. Therefore, you got the same error.

---

You also can use `router.isReady` which is defined in [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) package like below

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const Slug = ({proDetail}) => {
  const [slugValue, setSlugValue] = useState();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;
   
  useEffect(() => {
    if(router.isReady) {
       setSlugValue(slug);
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  if(!slugValue) {
     return null;
  }

  return (<div>title:{proDetail[slugValue]?.title}</div>)
}
export default Slug
```

This logic can help you to overcome the problem that you still allow empty `slug` for some cases.

*Note that I changed your component name from `slug` to `Slug` to avoid variable duplication which you also used in the component.*